# Hidden OK button because of window size in Tcl-tk

Tags: r, tcl, tk-toolkit

[image: The image showing the problem I have]

I have the following problem, described in the image above.
Actually sometimes when I use my script the "OK" button shows, and not at other times when I use the script. If I make the window bigger myself, using my mouse it will then show up (It was previously hidden because the window was to small). I don't understand why and I couldn't find anything really helpful on the internet. (Changing stuff like the value of `padx` and `pady` didn't work.)
There has to be a parameter to adjust the general window size but I can't find it.
My second problem is that if the strings are long as in the example; a scroll bar to scroll from left to right will show. I would like to show the full strings. I also don't know how to fix that, sadly.

Is there something to do about it?

My code is the following:

`noms_var_manif` is a character vector

```
win2 <- tktoplevel()

tkgrid(tk2label(win2, text = "Veuillez selectionner les variables appartenant à ce bloc",
                wraplength = 200, justify = "left"),
       padx = 10, pady = c(15, 5), sticky = "w", columnspan = 2)
# Note that 'selection' uses indices starting at 1, like R and not Tcl/Tk!

win2$env$lst <- tk2listbox(win2,values=noms_var_manif, height = 10, selectmode = "extended")
tkgrid(win2$env$lst, padx = 100, pady = c(10, 20), sticky = "ew", columnspan = 2)

onOK <- function() {
  select_var_bloc<- noms_var_manif[as.numeric(tkcurselection(win2$env$lst)) + 1]
  tkdestroy(win2)
  if (!length(select_var_bloc)) {
    msg <- "Il n'y a donc aucune variable dans ce bloc?"
  } else {
    msg <- paste0("Vous avez choisi les variables suivantes: ",
                  paste(select_var_bloc, collapse = ", "))
  }
  tkmessageBox(message = msg)
  win2$env$select_var_bloc= select_var_bloc
  tkdestroy(win2)
}

win2$env$butOK <-tk2button(win2, text = "OK ", width = -6, command = onOK)
tkgrid(win2$env$butOK, padx = 10, pady = c(10, 15))
tkwait.window(win2) 
select_var_bloc=win2$env$select_var_bloc
```

Comment: There should be something for measuring the width of a string in a particular font somewhere — it's called `font measure` in Tcl/Tk — but I don't know about what it's called in R. That'll help with working out what width of window you want.

Comment: Thank you for your help; I will try to find the corresponding parameters.

Comment: I found something that fixed both of my problems at once; if anyone ever stumbles across this problem. There was a parameter I was unaware of I just found in an example code. In tk2label() you can specifiy the width. Indeed, changing it to the following

`tk2label(win2, text = "Veuillez selectionner les variables appartenant à ce bloc", width=some number, 
                wraplength = 200, justify = "left")`

fixed the problem with a large enough number. I should have found that myself, sorry for that.

Comment: @JoelH You can self-answer your question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is (1) fix the height and width of the the listbox, and
(2) fix the height and width of the window so that it is big enough to allow the OK button to always show. You can also fix the window so that it cannot be resized.